# How to get max id from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table order_status_history, which store details status history. Table structure and data is shown in image as well as in text format. Id is PK here.

[order_status_history table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqjRY.png)

```
id  date        status  order_id    updated_by
1   11/12/2018  WAI         1       12365
2   11/12/2018  ACT         1       12365
3   11/12/2018  DEL         1       12365
4   11/12/2018  WAI         3       12365
5   11/12/2018  ACT         3       12365
6   11/12/2018  DEL         3       12365
7   11/12/2018  WAI         4       12365
8   11/12/2018  ACT         5       12365
9   11/12/2018  WAI         4       12365
10  11/12/2018  WAI         5       12365
11  11/12/2018  ACT         5       12365
12  11/13/2018  DEL         5       12365
13  11/13/2018  WAI         6       12365
14  11/13/2018  WAI         6       12365
15  11/13/2018  WAI         6       12365
```

I need to get all rows with max id, where status is WAI per order id for a specific date range. Required sample output is in yellow colour background in the image and also in below as text format.

```
id  date        status  order_id    updated_by
1   11/12/2018  WAI         1       12365
4   11/12/2018  WAI         3       12365
9   11/12/2018  WAI         4       12365
10  11/12/2018  WAI         5       12365
15  11/13/2018  WAI         6       12365
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: your question is not clear  ..in yellow  you have  5 rows ..  with 5 different  id  ..  add  a valid data sample  in text mode ... not an ambiguous picture  .

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @jarlh 10.1.26-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a derived table that gets the maximum id with the status of `'WAI'` per order in an aggregation.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(t2.id) id
                               FROM elbat t2
                               WHERE t2.status = 'WAI'
                               GROUP BY t2.order_id) x
                       ON x.id = t1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id = (select max(t1.id) from table t1 where t1.order_id = t.order_id and t1.status = 'WAI');
```